# Social Engineering Toolkit - Hosting website over VPN?

Tags: vpn, ip

I have set up a 2. Website Attack Vectors using SET and I get confused when I need to use IP for hosting website. So the question is how do I do it ? I have static ip by using vpn as well as many other people which use the same vpn have the same ip as I do. How do I set it up in SET ? Do I just do that : vpnip:random port ? Then later on I just type it in browser and it should work ?

Sorry for such a noobish question but I looked around the web and I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a random port will not work. Depending on your VPN provider, some have the option to 'claim' a port. This port will then be directed to you. Now you can use the VPNIP:PORTNUMBER.

Comment: BadSkilz thanks for answer as I was looking for that info for ages until I posted it in exchanged and it was redirected here. I quiet don't understand the process here. Can you explain it a bit more? I stuck on that bit: How I will be able to use that VPNIP with specific Port Number to host website where thousands of people have the same IP and there could be possibility that someone already is hosting something on it. I don't understand it :/. Can you give me more light on it please ?

Comment: I use a VPN from Mullvad for example, on their website i can login with my account information and choose "Port forwarding" they then generate a port that is directed to me. They do have a 3 hour free trail, so you can download the app and try for yourself.

Comment: Is there any free one that I can use for that purpose, not just for testing ?